# Unsure about the definition of a mean on a locally compact group.

Tags: group-theory, vector-spaces, normed-spaces, inner-products, amenability

I am reading Lectures on Amenability, and I am a little unsure about the definition of a mean:

Let $G$ be a locally compact group, and let $E$ be a subspace of $L^{\infty}(G)$ containing the constant functions. A mean on E is a functional $m \in E^{*}$ such that $\langle 1,m \rangle=\|m\|=1$

My understanding is that $L^{\infty}(G)$ is the set of functions on $G$ that are almost everywhere bounded, that $E^{*}$ is the dual space of $E$ ie the Banach-space of all bounded linear functionals $E \to \mathbb{C}$ with the operator norm.

My confusion is with the last part of the definition: $\langle 1,m \rangle=\|m\|=1$. Maybe I am missing something here, but what is the inner product of the dual space $E^{*}$? And what is the reasoning behind choosing this requirement?

Comment: No, say for $G$ $\sigma$-compact, $L^\infty(G)$ is the quotient of the space $\mathcal{L}^\infty(G)$ of bounded measurable functions on $G$ by the subspace of almost everywhere zero functions. (You can also write "space of a.e. bounded" instead of "space of bounded" without affecting the definition.) The significant nuance is that you mod out by a.e. zero functions. (However while this drastically changes the spaces, I'm not sure whether existence of an invariant mean on $\mathcal{L}^\infty(G)$ is enough to ensure amenability.)

Answer (score 1):

The inner product notation $\langle v, f\rangle$ for $v\in V, \, f\in V^*$ simply denotes the function value $f(v)$.

Comment: Oh, well that's a confusing use of notation, especially when the book hasn't defined it. Thanks for clearing that up.